# Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String' Swift Error

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

First of all, the other questions isn't the same as mine. ***I'm trying to get a single value from the data in Swift Xcode after retrieving the data from Firebase Firestore.*** Instead, it gives an error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String'

```
ref.getDocument { (document, err) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing: )) ?? "nil"
                print ("Cached document data: \(dataDescription)")
                profilename?.text = dataDescription["name"] as! String
            } else {
                print ("Document doesn't exist")
            }
        }
```

The error occurs at the

```
profilename?.text = dataDescription["name"] as! String
```

line.

The print of dataDescription is:

> Cached document data: ["email": test2@gmail.com, "name": Test2, "phone": 408-222-2222]

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: The error clearly states that `dataDescription` is a string which can be treated as array (index subscripted) but never as dictionary (key subscripted).

Comment: @vadian, so what should I do? I don't have much programming experience.

Comment: You do a print of dataDescription in your code, could you include the result?

Comment: Firstly, that's probably not how you want to use to use .map. Secondly, it's unclear what you're actually trying to do. Last, we don't know what's in *document*. Can you clarify the question with an explanation of what you're attempting to accomplish and include what your Firestore document structure looks like?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I got this all from the Firebase Firestore Docs and edited my post.

Comment: @Jay, edited my post to show the result

Comment: That's not how the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) reads. You've added `profilename?.text` and it's not the correct place for that. IMO, that particular documentation is pretty poor as it doesn't explain that it's taking the entire contents of a document and storing it as a single string in *dataDesription*. You can't really do anything what that. Let me provide a clearer example in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me address the question via an example. Suppose you have a FireStore with a users collection, and each document has a documentID of the users uid and stores their name within a field. It would look like this

```
users
   uid_1
      name: "Henry"
```

and we want to access the name field for this user. Here's the code that reads that document, prints the uid and name.

```
func readUsersName() {
    let users = self.db.collection("users")
    let thisUser = users.document("uid_1")
    thisUser.getDocument { documentSnapshot, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        let docId = documentSnapshot?.documentID
        let name = documentSnapshot?.get("name") as! String
        print(docId, name)
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation for swift actually does say this: docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
        print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}, but what you wrote said works. I didn't use the .get("name"), and I think that is why.

Comment: @Something  If you look at my above comment to your question, the specific issue is *You've added profilename?.text and it's not the correct place for that.*. The rest of the code is fine and matches the documentation but that line doesn't work for a string.